# How to move rows from one table to another and vice versa for aggregation and deaggregation using JSP HTML javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am trying to develop a Javascript code for moving selected rows within two tables. I am doing aggregation and deaggregation on selected rows. I have developed this code.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="card col-10 cardBody">
                    <div class="card-block">
                         <div class = "container">
                            <c:if test="${not empty loanEntries1}">
                                 <table id="table1" border="1" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
                                     <thead class="thead-default">
                                     <tr>
                                         <th>Sel</th>
                                         <th>Loan Id</th>
                                         <th>Amount</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                     <tbody>
                                     <c:forEach var="entry" items="${loanEntries1}">
                                         <tr>
                                             <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                                             <td><c:out  value ="${entry.loanId}"/></td>
                                             <td><c:out  value ="${entry.amount}"/></td>
                                         </tr>
                                     </c:forEach>
                                     </tbody>
                                 </table>
                            </c:if>

                             <div style="float:left">
                                <c:if test="${not empty loanEntries2}">
                                    <input type= "button" id="aggregate" value="aggregate" onclick="aggregate()">
                                    <input type= "button" id="deaggregate" value="deaggregate" onclick="deaggregate()">
                                 <input type= "button" id="cancel" value="cancel"style="float:left" >
                                </c:if>
                             </div>

                            <c:if test="${not empty loanEntries2}">
                                 <table id="table2" border="1" style="float:left">
                                     <thead class="thead-default">
                                     <tr>
                                         <th>Sel</th>
                                         <th>Loan Id</th>
                                         <th>Amount</th>
                                     </tr>
                                     </thead>
                                     <tbody>
                                     <c:forEach var="entry" items="${loanEntries2}">
                                         <tr>
                                             <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                                             <td><c:out  value ="${entry.loanId}"/></td>
                                             <td><c:out  value ="${entry.amount}"/></td>
                                         </tr>
                                     </c:forEach>
                                     </tbody>
                                 </table>
                            </c:if>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("in block");

        function aggregate(){
            var row = $('#table1 tbody tr td input.checkbox:checked').closest('tr').clone();
            console.log("==>",row);
            $('#table2 tbody').append(row);
            $('#table1 tbody tr td input.checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();

        };

        function deaggregate(){
            var row = $('#table2 tbody tr td input.checkbox:checked').closest('tr').clone();
            console.log("rows:",row);

//            var row = $('#table2 tbody tr td input.checkbox:checked').parent().clone();
            $('#table1 tbody').append(row);
            $('#table2 tbody tr td input.checkbox:checked').closest('tr').remove();

        };


</script>
```

But when I am executing this code I am facing one issue. When I select one row  from table 1 and aggregate into table two, at the time of deaggregation it is creating two rows in the table 1 with same fields. Like this if I again aggregate four rows are formed with the same row details. I need only one row to be created in the table in which it is moved.